# How to convert Java TimeStamp into ms access Date?

Tags: java, ms-access, timestamp

I would like to insert a java Timestamp into an msaccess database but I am getting an error which is listed below. The ms-access field has been set to a DATE datatype. Any advise would be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Here's my DAO class method:

```
public void addSale(String saleDetails, String saleTotal, Timestamp saleTimestamp) 
                    throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

Statement myStatement = getConnection();
String sql = "INSERT INTO Sale (SaleDetails, SaleTotal, SaleTimestamp)"
            + " VALUES ('"+saleDetails+"','"+saleTotal+"','"+saleTimestamp+"')";

myStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
closeConnection();
```

My DTO method:

```
public void storeSale(String saleDetails, String saleTotal, Timestamp saleTimestamp){
   DAO dao = DAO.getDAO();
   try {
      dao.addSale(saleDetails, saleTotal, saleTimestamp);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Sale.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

My Timestamp method:

```
public Timestamp addTimestamp(){ 
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
}
```

Error:
    [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Did you the ms-access date format? if yes just use simpledateformatter to parse it

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert your `java.util.Data` to a `java.sql.Date` or if you need the precision of the `java.sql.Timestamp` change your Database type to `TIMESTAMP`

some code to create a `java.sql.Date`:

```
 java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
 long t = today.getTime();
 java.sql.Date dt = new java.sql.Date(t);
```

You can then put the java.sql.Date in your Database, did always work for me.

For Info:

- [`java.sql.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) corresponds to SQL `DATE` it stores *years, months and days* while *hour, minute, second and millisecond* are ignored. Additionally `sql.Date` isn't tied to timezones.
- [`java.sql.Time`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) corresponds to SQL `TIME` andonly contains information about *hour, minutes, seconds and milliseconds*.
- [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) corresponds to SQL `TIMESTAMP` which is the date to the nanosecond (*note that `util.Date` only supports milliseconds!*).

Comment: Hi I make the changes you mention:                                public Timestamp addTimestamp(){ 
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
long time = today.getTime();        
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(time);
return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
}                                                                   Still getting the same error...is the ms access date datatype correct?

Comment: You did not get my point. Add the java.sql.Date to the database and not the Timestamp or change the database type to TIMESTAMP.

Comment: With java.sql.Date would I get the date and time to be written to the database?...I'm still a novice in java..thanks for your patience.

Comment: If you need Date and Time, you have 2 options. Use 2 fields... or use the Timestamp as type in your DB

Comment: Are you sure that ms access supports the timestamp type... consider 2 fields, one for date one for time