# How to convert Timestamp(date.getTime()) into ms access Date?

Tags: java, ms-access, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Java TimeStamp into ms access Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322934/how-to-convert-java-timestamp-into-ms-access-date)

I would like to insert a java Timestamp into an msaccess database but I am getting an error which is listed below. The ms-access field has been set to a DATE datatype. Any advise would be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Here's my DAO class method:

```
public void addSale(String saleDetails, String saleTotal, Timestamp saleTimestamp) 
                    throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

Statement myStatement = getConnection();
String sql = "INSERT INTO Sale (SaleDetails, SaleTotal, SaleTimestamp)"
            + " VALUES ('"+saleDetails+"','"+saleTotal+"','"+saleTimestamp+"')";

myStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
closeConnection();
```

My DTO method:

```
public void storeSale(String saleDetails, String saleTotal, Timestamp saleTimestamp){
   DAO dao = DAO.getDAO();
   try {
      dao.addSale(saleDetails, saleTotal, saleTimestamp);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Sale.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

My Timestamp method:

```
public Timestamp addTimestamp(){ 
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    long time = today.getTime();
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(time);
    return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Error:
    [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Changes Recommemded:

```
public void addSale(String saleDetails, String saleTotal) 
                        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

     Statement myStatement = getConnection();
     String sql = "INSERT INTO Sale (SaleDetails, SaleTotal, SaleTimestamp)"
                + " VALUES ('"+saleDetails+"','"+saleTotal+"',Now())";

     myStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
     closeConnection();
```

New error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in string in query expression ''Now())'.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:287)
```

Comment: Yep, and only two hours ago, "with an accepted answer", what was wrong with the original thread @Adesh?

Comment: Hang on, and another one and hour earlier than that, is this OCD or is there a magic secret revelead after posting three times??

Comment: Actually each question is slightly different ...but you are right. I should not have accepted the answer that quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the db engine to use its `Now()` function for the value you insert into your `SaleTimestamp` field.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Sale (SaleDetails, SaleTotal, SaleTimestamp)"
            + " VALUES ('"+saleDetails+"','"+saleTotal+"',Now())";
```

Java should have some way to write a text string to a file or console.  Suggest you find and use such a method in order to give yourself the opportunity to view the completed SQL statement you're asking the db engine to execute.  Based on what I saw in another Java question, I'll suggest ...

```
System.out.println(sql);
```

Unfortunately I don't know Java.  If that suggestion does not work, find another way to do it.

Comment: Hi HansUp  - this gives a syntax error, which is as follows- string in query expression ''Now())'

Comment: And that error comes from the Access db engine via ODBC?  I don't understand why the db engine would complain about `Now()`.  Can you display the finished `sql` string you're giving `myStatement.executeUpdate()` and test it in Access directly and/or show us the text?

Comment: No, the error comes up in Netbeans. i have added the text above.

Comment: I don't know Java, so doubt I can help without seeing the full text of the SQL statement you're asking Access' db engine to execute.  However, based on the error message you added to the question, is it possible the statement includes a stray single quote before the `Now()` function? ... `Syntax error in string in query expression ''Now())'`

Comment: Not sure how I had the code on two lines if there was a stray quote, but now I placed the sql string on one line and netbeans throws- Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating parameters in a string, you should use prepared statements as explained in [this article.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) In your case the code should look like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatetement("INSERT INTO Sale (SaleDetails, SaleTotal, SaleTimestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
stmt.setObject(1, saleDetails);
stmt.setObject(2, saleTotal);
stmt.setObject(3, saleTimestamp);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```